# Is there any web service to get the weather data for the cities all round the world [over a period of time like one year]?

Tags: web-services, data-mining, weather

Any web service to get the monthly min/max temperatures for cities over a period of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202092/where-can-i-find-free-and-open-data - it's not specific to *this* question, but may be helpful :)